# Oracle - optimising SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables - countries (id, name) and users (id, name, country_id). Each user belongs to one country. I want to select 10 random users from the same random country. However, there are countries that have less than 10 users, so I can't use them. I need to select only from those countries, that have at least 10 users.

I can write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT * 
   FROM users u
   {MANY_OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS}
   WHERE u.country_id = 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c.id 
      FROM countries c
      JOIN 
      (
        SELECT users.country_id, COUNT(*) as cnt 
        FROM users 
        {MANY_OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS}
        GROUP BY users.country_id
      ) X ON X.country_id = c.id 
      WHERE X.cnt >= 10 
      ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
    ) Y
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
  ) 
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
) Z WHERE ROWNUM < 10
```

However, In my real scenario, I have more conditions and joins to other tables for determining which user is applicable. By using this query, I must have these conditions on two places - in query that actually selects data and in the count subquery.

Is there any way how to write query like this but without having those other conditions on two places (which is probably not good performance-wise)?

Comment: You could create a view for the `{MANY_OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS}`...

Comment: Hi, I think best way to optimize here is to use proper join sometimes nested queries are costly. instead of nested queries use left or inner joins depends upon the need.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto for the sake of anyone having to maintain this in a long run - don't hide complexity in views

Comment: I suspect you will get some readability by doing some sub-query refactoring and depending on what your 'OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS' are then its likely you will refer to them just the once in one or more CTE's (common table expressions) I suggest you look up examples of the WITH clause for the SELECT statement in Oracle docs. This is a start - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2129904

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CTE for the user criteria to avoid repeating the logic and to allow the DB to cache that set once (though in my experience the DB isn't as good at that as it should be, so check your execution plan).

I'm more of a Sql Server guy than Oracle, and syntax is subtly different so this may need some tweaks yet, but try this:

```
WITH SafeUsers (ID, Name, country_id) As
(
   --criteria for users only has to specified here
   SELECT ID, Name, country_id
   FROM users
   WHERE ... 
),
RandomCountry (ID) As 
( 
    SELECT ID 
    FROM (
        SELECT u.country_id AS ID
        FROM SafeUsers u -- but we reference it HERE
        GROUP BY u.country_id
        HAVING COUNT(u.Id) >= 10
        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
    ) c
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)
SELECT u.* 
FROM (
    SELECT s.*        
    FROM SafeUsers s -- and HERE
    INNER JOIN RandomCountry r ON s.country_id = r.ID
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
) u
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

And by removing nesting and introducing names for each intermediate step, this query is suddenly **much** easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. Much more readable, faster and returning correct results. And thanks for introducing me to CTE as well, I have never came into contact with this. I already like it :)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a view
for

```
  create view user_with_many_cond as 
  SELECT * 
  FROM users u
  {MANY_OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS}
```

ths looking to your query 
You could use having instead of a where outside the query
The order by seems could be placed inside the inner query
so the filter for one row

```
  SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT * 
     FROM user_with_many_cond u
     WHERE u.country_id = 
    (
        SELECT c.id 
        FROM countries c
        JOIN 
        (
          SELECT users.country_id, COUNT(*) as cnt 
          FROM user_with_many_cond
          GROUP BY users.country_id
          HAVING cnt >=10
          ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
        ) X ON X.country_id = c.id 
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ) 
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
  ) Z WHERE ROWNUM < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

To get countries with more than 10 users:

```
  SELECT users.country_id
          , row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as rn 
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY users.country_id having count(*) > 10
```

Use this as a sub-query to choose a country and grab some users:

```
with ctry as (
  SELECT users.country_id
          , row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as ctry_rn 
  FROM users 
  GROUP BY users.country_id having count(*) > 10
)
  , usr as (
      select user_id
             ,  row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as usr_rn 
      from ctry
      join users 
           on users.country_id = ctry.country_id
      where ctry.ctry_rn = 1
) 
select users.*
from usr
     join users 
     on users.user_id = usr.user_id
where usr.usr_rn <= 10
/
```

This example ignores your `{MANY_OTHER_JOINS_AND_CONDITIONS}`: please inject them back where you need them.